# Quick question on a probability problem

Tags: probability, geometry

> A point is chosen at random inside a triangle with height $h$ and base
>   of length $b$. What is the probability that the perpendicular distance
>   from the point to the base is larger than a given value d with $0<d<h$?

I know that the points for which the perpendicular distance to the base is greater than $d$ form a triangle with height $h-d$ and that the desired probability is given by the ratio of this triangle to a larger triangle of height $h$ and base $b$. My question it: how can I find the base of the smaller triangle in order to compute its area? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to find the base of the smaller triangle. Draw a line parallel to the base at a distance $d$ from the base. The top small triangle is similar to the original large triangle. Use the property of similar triangles:
$$\frac{A}{B}=\left(\frac{a_1}{b_1}\right)^2,$$
where $A,B$ are areas, $a_1,b_1$ are corresponding sides or heights. Hence:
$$P(p>d)=\frac{A}{B}=\left(\frac{h-d}{h}\right)^2.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The smaller triangle shares an angle and has parallel sides to the larger triangle, so they are similar triangles.